# Stencil.js - How to supply JSX templates with template literals externally?

Tags: jsx, stenciljs

I'm developing a widget like component that shows current share price data. However, I want to supply the JSX template externally as the layout requirement differs from client to client.

I tried two approaches with no luck. In the first approach, I supplied a template as a slot. In the second, I made a  tag and tried to get it rendered from the component's render method.

Approach - 1: Slots

```
// Inside "index.html"
<my-component>
<span>{ this.price }</span>
</my-component>

// Inside "my-component.tsx"
...

componentWillLoad() {
// code to fetch dynamic data goes here
}

render() {
return (
<slot />
);
}
```

Approach - 2: Template

```
// Inside "index.html"

<template id="ticker-widget-layout">
<span>{ this.price }</span>
</template>
```

In fact, I poorly failed to even get implemented the second approach as I received multiple errors.

I expect the user (here user means someone using my component to build their widget) should be able to set the layout externally. Plus, the placeholders/template literals should be rendered with the actual value. Currently, my component renders the template literal itself.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options to solve the problem is to use a render prop. In render prop scenario you pass a render function from parent to child and the child is responsible to render the content with the relevant data. For further reading go to [Render Props in Stencil](https://medium.com/@gilfink/render-props-in-stencil-d9ce7f9d343b).

Comment: This is a good solution, but it requires that the children be components which is different than what the OP is asking. However, I think this is the "correct" approach.

Comment: @Gil Fink thanks for pointing to this solution. I was looking for that

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, `this` is referring to the parent `<my-component>`. But `this` is a javascript construct that has no meaning in DOM except within a `<script>`. You have access to `this` inside your component, where you also have access to content inside your slot(s). Therefore you could pass the data in to the external 'template' from within your component. That might look something like:

Usage:

```
<my-component>
  <span slot="price"></span>
</my-component>
```

Component:

```
@Element() el: HTMLMyComponentElement;

componentWillLoad() {
  this.loadSharePriceData().then(data => {
    const price = data.price;
    const priceElement = this.el.querySelector('[slot="price"]'); // or some predefined selector
    priceElement.innerHTML = price;
  });
}
```

This seems sort of hacky to me, and you'd have to be very specific about how the user specifies the layout and identifies where the various data would appear, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @G. Tranter. I tried this approach. However, I would have to select each slot items this way to be able to replace them with actual value. I'm expecting it to be rendered by the web component itself with actual values received from the API response.

Comment: Whatever way you slice it, the "children" would have to instruct the "parent" about what data is needed and where it goes. You did that in your examples with `{ this.price }`. Slots is one approach. You could just as easily use an attribute instead of slots - e.g. `<span stock-data="price">`, or a custom component do do the same thing. You want the parent to "push" the data into the child, but I think you should have the child "pull" the data from the "parent" since only the child can know what and where. You might be better off with a service-worker kind of approach instead of a component.